# SHA 256 Output Word length

Tags: encryption, hash, md5

I'm a Java Programmer.

I happend to begin learning about Encryption. SHA

and I found, for example SHA-256 print 256 bit length output.

```
I tried for example "Hello World", and I got result "A591A6D40BF420404A011733CFB7B190D62C65BF0BCDA32B57B277D9AD9F146E"
```

I expected 32 length word. because 1 byte = 8 bit. so 256/8 = 32.

But Why is that's length is 64?

Please teach me. and Any Answers or commnent will be apprieciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each byte is two Hexadecimal digits.

One byte, two nibbles: 1111 1110 results in two Hexadecimal digits: FE

The length of the SHA 256 is 64 in Hexadecimal because it contains 32 bytes represented by 64 Hexadecimal digits.